# Deployment of QGIS 2.18.11

Tags: qgis, installation, deployment

Does anyone have any guidance for me for packaging QGIS 2.18.11 setup via **sccm**?

I have already tried `/s switch` but still shows a UI. Needs to be a silent/unattended installation as this will be installed via SCCM and will need to have no user interaction.